# Ag-grid angular : Pass event handler from dispatchEvent()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events, ag-grid

I'm using [ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com) - Angular (Angular 2 typescript)  I've set it up like this:

My template :

```
<ag-grid-angular (cell-clicked)="cellClicked($event)" ...
 ... ... [gridOptions]="gridOptions">

</ag-grid-angular>
```

My component:

```
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
      onCellClicked: (event) => {
        console.log(event);
        //open modal with the event parameter

      },
      ....
      ....
      onGridReady: (ev) =>{
        // console.log('gridoptions',this.gridOptions.api);
        this.gridIsReady(ev);
      },
    };
```

I have a use case where I need to traverse to the next cell and trigger a cellClicked event so that I can open up the modal for the next focused cell and let the user do something, so I do it like this :

```
this.gridOptions.api.tabToNextCell();
this.gridOptions.api.dispatchEvent('cellClicked', <what do i put here> );
```

the **tabToNextCell()** puts the focus on the next cell which is expected, and then I dispatch a cellClicked event and the event is fired using the dispatchEvent(), except that the event parameter becomes null, how do i get the event object for the focused cell?